# How can I add a preloaded "busy" animation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using the attached code which I have stripped down to try to get the basics working first.

I am taking the text that is input into the textbox and using it as a variable in the PHP file 'testnewsearchresults.php'. Once this is run, the results are then displayed inside the 'result' `<div>`.

The problem is that the PHP script is quite long and so the page just appears to not be doing anything.

I have read about this but I cannot work out how to add a preloaded animation to run while it is loading. Is this possible or do I need to change my current code?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>


<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Critera" id="name"/>
<br>
<center><input type="button" onclick="post();" value="Submit"/>   </center>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>

<script type= "text/javascript" >

function post()
{

var name =$('#name').val();

$.post('testnewsearchresults.php',{postname:name},function(data){$('#result').html(data);});

}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loading image to #result on form POST with

```
$('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif" id="loading" />');
```

Full code:

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
        </head>
        <body>


        <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Critera" id="name"/>
        <br>
        <center><input type="button" onclick="post();" value="Submit"/>   </center>
        </form>

        <div id="result"></div>

        <script type= "text/javascript" >

        function post()
        {
            $('#result').html('<img src="loading.gif" id="loading" />');
            var name =$('#name').val();

            $.post('testnewsearchresults.php',{
                postname:name

            },function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);

            });

        }
        </script>


        </body>
    </html>
```

Demo (i am adding text 'loading' instead of an image in the demo, you can add an image if you prefer) http://codepen.io/aharen/pen/MwjyZE

Comment: what would I do if i wanted to be able to centre the image? sorry if that is simple question

Comment: Glad to help :) you can use css to centre the image, try adding this to your `<head>` right before closing it `<style type="text/css">#result img {text-align: center;}</style>`

Comment: cool thanks 1 last thing when i try to put then back into my site the variable won't pass through. You obviously know the code for the text form however the new form:

Comment: <form>  
<div class="row">     
<div class="col-md-3">  
</div>   
<div class="col-md-6">
<center><font size="6" color=#4097BF >Search</font></center>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Critera" id="name" class="form-control"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">  
</div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<br>
<center><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="post();" value="Search"/></center>
</div>
</div>
</form>

Comment: sorry don't know how to add code to the add comment section:-s

that code though loads the page but does pass the variable and i can't figure out what is blocking it

Comment: At a glance i don't see any reason why it should not. Is jQuery loading properly?? and is there any error on console when you submit form??

Comment: Not that I can see. As if I put both forms on the same page the demo form works and the other 1 doesn't. I wondered if it was because its inside of bootstrap divs? I can't work it's out. Must be somewhere JavaScript doesn't like as even if I change the new form attributes to match the demo 1s it still doesn't load.

Comment: i just tested with your bootstrap form code and it is working for me, have you got the `#result` div?

Comment: Yea. The content of the result div loads but I put a check in to see if the variable was transferred and it wasn't? It is on the demo form but not this form?

Comment: Unless you have another element with the id `#name` on the page it should work. Any output on the browser's developer console?

Comment: Hey sorry for a delay in responding. I finally got that side working. I was wondering if instead of wiping the page value and replacing it with an image can i have the image appear above the page content while the new content loads?

Comment: Yes you can, take a look at this pen http://codepen.io/aharen/pen/jPVRyp you can create a separate div as a loading indicator and display it on form submit and hide it when it completes :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It wasn't exactly what i was looking for but i think that was more down to my explanation. When i meant on top of i didn't mean above. I mean almost like an animation that is on top of the current page like adding a new layer in photoshop if that makes any sense?

Comment: Hi, you mean like a transparent overlay? take a look at the codepen http://codepen.io/aharen/pen/MwjyZE did i get you right :)

Comment: Yea thats what i want but obviously with like a loading animation taking place on that overlay. Is it possible to add an animation to that overlay?

Comment: Yes you can. You could use an image with the loading animation or with CSS or even text effect with JavaScript :)